# Google Cloud Speech to text API call fails due to invalid authentication credentials on Android

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-platform, google-api, speech-to-text

I'm trying to use the [google cloud speech to text API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text) in my android client. I have enabled the API in the Google Cloud and in the console I have generate a new key like this: "Create credentials" -> "Service account" (added details) -> "Create and Continue". This has generated a JSON file that contains this params:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "",
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "",
  "client_email": "",
  "client_id": "",
  "auth_uri": "",
  "token_uri": "",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "",
  "universe_domain": ""
}
```

I have added this JSON file in the `raw`  dir in my android project (this is just a POC so not to worried about security at this point)

Next is the android code:

```
val req = RecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
               .setConfig(RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                        .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.AMR_WB)
                        .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                        .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                        .build())
                    .setAudio(RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
                        .setContent(fileByteString))
                        .build()


            val speechClient = SpeechClient.create(SpeechSettings.newBuilder()              .setCredentialsProvider{GoogleCredentials.fromStream(this.resources.openRawResource(R.raw.credentials)) }


            val response = speechClient.recognize(req)

Log.d(TAG, "we have a count of ${response.resultsCount} hits on the  audio file")

            val results = response.resultsList
```

When the `speechClient.recognize(req)`  fun is called, the API sends back this error message:

```
com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnauthenticatedException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNAUTHENTICATED: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptionFactory.createException(ApiExceptionFactory.java:116)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:98)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcApiExceptionFactory.create(GrpcApiExceptionFactory.java:66)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionCallable$ExceptionTransformingFuture.onFailure(GrpcExceptionCallable.java:97)
        at com.google.api.core.ApiFutures$1.onFailure(ApiFutures.java:84)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures$CallbackListener.run(Futures.java:1127)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.DirectExecutor.execute(DirectExecutor.java:31)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.executeListener(AbstractFuture.java:1286)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.complete(AbstractFuture.java:1055)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.setException(AbstractFuture.java:807)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$GrpcFuture.setException(ClientCalls.java:574)
        at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$UnaryStreamToFuture.onClose(ClientCalls.java:544)
        at io.grpc.PartialForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(PartialForwardingClientCallListener.java:39)
        at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:23)
        at io.grpc.ForwardingClientCallListener$SimpleForwardingClientCallListener.onClose(ForwardingClientCallListener.java:40)
        at com.google.api.gax.grpc.ChannelPool$ReleasingClientCall$1.onClose(ChannelPool.java:541)
        at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:489)
        at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:453)
        at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:486)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:567)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:71)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:735)
        at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:716)
        at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37)
        at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
     Suppressed: com.google.api.gax.rpc.AsyncTaskException: Asynchronous task failed
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ApiExceptions.callAndTranslateApiException(ApiExceptions.java:57)
        at com.google.api.gax.rpc.UnaryCallable.call(UnaryCallable.java:112)
        at com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient.recognize(SpeechClient.java:252)
```

Does anyone know how to  auth correctly when calling this API please?

I have also tried to generate  OAuth & Service Key type of credentials in the Google Cloud Console but I was getting a different error saying something like "Credentials don't contain field `type`"

Answer (score 1):

Please, consider review [this related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65106296/13942448), it is defined for `TextToSpeechSettings` but I think that the solution provided could be of application here as well.

As suggested, basically you need to create a valid `GoogleCredentials` object from the content of your service account json file:

```java
// R.raw.credential points to the downloaded credential.json file
InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credential); 
GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
```

And then, use the obtained credentials to initialize your `SpeechClient`.

For instance, adapting the code from my original answer:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.gax.core.CredentialsProvider;
import com.google.api.gax.core.FixedCredentialsProvider;
import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionAudio;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognitionConfig;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeRequest;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.RecognizeResponse;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechClient;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechRecognitionResult;
import com.google.cloud.speech.v1.SpeechSettings;
import com.google.protobuf.ByteString;

public class RecognitionActivity extends Activity {

  // Your activity definition

  private void performRecognition(ByteString fileByteString) throws IOException {
    // R.raw.credential points to the downloaded credential.json file
    // I tested my code locally in a laptop using
    // GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(new FileInputStream("/path/to/credentials.json"));
    InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credential);
    GoogleCredentials credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
    // You can use ServiceAccountCredentials as well instead of the line above:
    // ServiceAccountCredentials credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(stream);
    CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials);
    SpeechSettings speechSettings = SpeechSettings.newBuilder()
        .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
        .build();

    SpeechClient speechClient = SpeechClient.create(speechSettings);

    // The rest of your code

    RecognizeRequest req = RecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
        .setConfig(RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
            .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.AMR_WB)
            .setLanguageCode("en-US")
            .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
            .build())
        .setAudio(RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
            .setContent(fileByteString))
        .build();

    RecognizeResponse response = speechClient.recognize(req);

    Log.d(TAG, "we have a count of " + response.getResultsCount() + " hits on the  audio file")

    List<SpeechRecognitionResult> results = response.getResultsList();
    
    // Handle results
  }
}
```

In kotlin (please, forgive me for any inaccuracy) it would look like this:

```kotlin
private fun performRecognition(fileByteString: ByteString) {
    // R.raw.credential points to the downloaded credential.json file
    val stream: InputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.credential)
    val credentials = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(stream);
    // val credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromStream(stream)
    val credentialsProvider = FixedCredentialsProvider.create(credentials)
    val speechSettings = SpeechSettings.newBuilder()
            .setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
            .build()

    val speechClient = SpeechClient.create(speechSettings)

    // The rest of your code
    val req = RecognizeRequest.newBuilder()
            .setConfig(RecognitionConfig.newBuilder()
                    .setEncoding(RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.AMR_WB)
                    .setLanguageCode("en-US")
                    .setSampleRateHertz(16000)
                    .build())
            .setAudio(RecognitionAudio.newBuilder()
                    .setContent(fileByteString))
            .build()

    val response = speechClient.recognize(req)

    Log.d(TAG, "we have a count of ${response.resultsCount} hits on the  audio file")

    val results = response.resultsList

    // Handle results
}
```

Please, be sure that you followed the [necessary steps](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/before-you-begin) for setting up the Speech API, especially those related to [configuring the service account](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/before-you-begin#create_a_service_account).

The service account must be able to interact with the Speech API, assigning a convenient role to it such as `Cloud Speech Client`:

[image: Cloud Speech Client role]

As described in the aforementioned documentation you can do it from the GCP Console or using [the command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42564112/adding-roles-to-service-accounts-on-google-cloud-platform-using-rest-api).

Comment: Hi @jccampanero! Thank you for your response! I have tried your proposed fix but unfortunately  the setCredentialsProvider  does not like the FixedCredentialsProvider type and is expecting a type Credentials.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @androidenthusiast. It is very strange, I think it should work properly, `setCredentialsProvider` requires a `CredentialsProvider`. I updated my code to make the code snippet more complete (sorry, I implemented it in pure Java): please, could you double check the proposed solution and see if it works? Thank you.

Comment: @androidenthusiast Sorry for disturbing you. Did your program compile in the end? Are you still facing the issue? Can I help you in any way?